# How do Typescript templates work with circular references and inheritance?

Tags: typescript, templates

I'm attempting to create a configurable Scene class that functions as a factory for creating entities. An Entity constructor would be passed into the Scene constructor, and that constructor would be called when addEntity is called on the scene. The problem arrives when I try to store a reference to the scene on the Entity. When I do this, the Typescript compiler says

```
source.ts:36:31 - error TS2344: Type 'Entity' does not satisfy the constraint 'EntityBase'.
  Types of property 'm_scene' are incompatible.
    Type 'SceneBase<Entity>' is not assignable to type 'SceneBase<EntityBase>'.
      Types of property 'm_entityConstructor' are incompatible.
        Type 'EntityBaseConstructor<Entity>' is not assignable to type 'EntityBaseConstructor<EntityBase>'.
          Types of parameters 'scene' and 'scene' are incompatible.
            Type 'SceneBase<EntityBase>' is not assignable to type 'SceneBase<Entity>'.
              Types of property 'm_entityConstructor' are incompatible.
                Type 'EntityBaseConstructor<EntityBase>' is not assignable to type 'EntityBaseConstructor<Entity>'.
                  Type 'EntityBase' is not assignable to type 'Entity'.

36 class Scene extends SceneBase<Entity> {
                                 ~~~~~~

  source.ts:28:11
    28   private m_transform: Transform;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~
    'm_transform' is declared here.


Found 1 error.
```

Is there a way to accomplish my goals?

```
    class Transform {

    }

    type EntityBaseConstructor<IEntity extends EntityBase> = new (scene: SceneBase<IEntity>) => IEntity;

    class EntityBase {

        private m_scene: SceneBase<this>;

        public constructor(scene: SceneBase<any>) {
            this.m_scene = scene;
        }

    }

    class SceneBase<IEntity extends EntityBase> {

        private m_entityConstructor: EntityBaseConstructor<IEntity>;

        constructor(entityConstructor: EntityBaseConstructor<IEntity>) {
            this.m_entityConstructor = entityConstructor;
        }

        public addEntity(): IEntity {
            return new this.m_entityConstructor(this);
        }

    }

    class Entity extends EntityBase {

        private m_transform: Transform;

        constructor(scene: Scene) {
            super(scene);
            this.m_transform = new Transform();
        }

    }

    class Scene extends SceneBase<Entity> {

        constructor() {
            super(Entity);
        }

    }
```

Comment: which version of typescript (`tsc --version`) did you use? Some particular parameter? With the latest (v3.2.4) your code seems to work without any issue.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using v3.2.4, and compiling it straight with tsc does work, but using webpack (v4.28.3) and awesome-typescript-loader (v5.2.1) with typescript (v3.2.4) results in that error. Additionally, Intellisense in both Cloud 9 editor and Visual Studio tell me there is an error.

Comment: It turns out when I use tsc --strict it throws the error. I'd like to continue compiling with this switch if possible.

Comment: Indeed, I can reproduce it with --strict. You'll find now in my answer a complete analysis of the problem + a fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we keep the errors to a bare minimum we see this:

```
  Types of property 'm_scene' are incompatible.
   ...
    Type 'EntityBase' is not assignable to type 'Entity'.
```

So it seems related to this:

```
class EntityBase {
  private m_scene: SceneBase<this>; // <-

  public constructor(scene: SceneBase<any>) {
    this.m_scene = scene;
  }
}
```

It's a polymorphic `this` type and you have a covariant/contravariant conflicting constraints that causes this problem (look at the explanation below). One way to solve it would be to have a `SceneBase<any>` instead.

Another way, uses [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), this is another way of achieving polymorphism. So basically, instead of having to use a polymorphic `this` in `EntityBase`, you could declare the base class this way `class EntityBase<IEntity extends EntityBase<IEntity>>` and `IEntity` directly. So here is the modified code using CRTP:

```
class Transform {}

type EntityBaseConstructor<IEntity extends EntityBase<IEntity>> = new (
  scene: SceneBase<IEntity>
) => IEntity;

class EntityBase<IEntity extends EntityBase<IEntity>> {
  private m_scene: SceneBase<IEntity>;

  public constructor(scene: SceneBase<IEntity>) {
    this.m_scene = scene;
  }
}

class SceneBase<IEntity extends EntityBase<IEntity>> {
  private m_entityConstructor: EntityBaseConstructor<IEntity>;

  constructor(entityConstructor: EntityBaseConstructor<IEntity>) {
    this.m_entityConstructor = entityConstructor;
  }

  public addEntity(): IEntity {
    return new this.m_entityConstructor(this);
  }
}

class Entity extends EntityBase<Entity> {
  private m_transform: Transform;

  constructor(scene: Scene) {
    super(scene);
    this.m_transform = new Transform();
  }
}

class Scene extends SceneBase<Entity> {
  constructor() {
    super(Entity);
  }
}

const s = new Scene();
```

---

An explanation of why `this` type doesn't not work here:

1. In order to construct `Scene`, you need a `Entity`
2. Since we have both `class Scene extends SceneBase<Entity>` and `class SceneBase<IEntity extends EntityBase>`, we should have `Entity extends EntityBase` (duh)
3. Now, `Entity` extending `EntityBase` means that `Entity` should be assignable to `EntityBase`
4. Which also means that `SceneBase<Entity>` should be assignable to `SceneBase<EntityBase>`, since Entity has a field `m_scene: SceneBase<Entity>` and `EntityBase` has a field `m_scene: SceneBase<EntityBase>`
5. Now via the definition of `SceneBase` we see that `EntityBaseConstructor<Entity>` should be assignable to `EntityBaseConstructor<EntityBase>`
6. The first constructor type takes a `SceneBase<Entity>` (which is more specific) while the second one take a `SceneBase<EntityBase>` (which is less specific) but we can't have `SceneBase<EntityBase>` assignable to `SceneBase<Entity>`. We say that EntityBaseConstructor is [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Contravariant_method_argument_type) on its type parameter. The following example illustrates this:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

type FunA = (x: A) => void;
type FunB = (x: B) => void;

const fA: FunA = () => {};
const fB: FunB = () => {};

// While B is assignable to A, (_:B) => ... is not assignable to (_:A) => ...
const testA: FunA = fb; // error
// it's the other way around
const testB: FunB = fA; // this works
```